# Image gets cut off when using html2canvas more than once at a time

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I'm trying to create an image of a div in my html page using html2canvas. When I run the below function for the first time, the image is saved correctly. However, if I click the button to save the image for a second time, the image is saved with the bottom and right sides of the image cut off and the top and left sides show a black background. It just seems like the area it is trying to capture has been offset once it has already been saved the first time. I have already made sure there is no padding or margin being added to the div when the button is clicked.

```
function captureAndSaveAsImage() {
    // Reset the window scroll position to the top
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    // Capture the content inside the 'matrixTableContainer' div
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('matrixTableContainer')).then(function (canvas) {
        // Convert the canvas to a data URL (JPEG or PNG)
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

        // Create a temporary anchor element
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = imgData;
        a.download = 'screenshot.jpg';

        // Trigger a click event on the anchor to initiate the download
        var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
            view: window,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: false
        });
        a.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    });
}
```

I've also tried to refresh the page automatically once the first image has been produced. However, the user is filling out a form and the image should be a screenshot of their results. This means that the results on all the dropdowns are lost when the page is refreshed

Answer (score 0):

if your div 'matrixTableContainer' contains multiple divs you can write a loop or manually include all the divs in a doc and then download the doc.

step 1 : declare doc as 'var doc= new jsPDF();'
step 2 : doc.addImage(imgData,15,20,90,imgHeight)
step 3 : download the doc.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35523640)

Answer (score 0):

This way, you'll always capture the original state of the div, even if changes have been made dynamically.

Here's an updated version of your function that includes the cloning step:

```
function captureAndSaveAsImage() {
window.scrollTo(0, 0);

var containerClone = document.getElementById('matrixTableContainer').cloneNode(true);

html2canvas(containerClone).then(function (canvas) {
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = imgData;
    a.download = 'screenshot.jpg';

    var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: false
    });
    a.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
});
```

}

By cloning the content before capturing, you ensure that the html2canvas function always captures the original state of the 'matrixTableContainer' div, regardless of any changes that might have occurred after the first capture. This should resolve the issue of the image being cut off and showing a black background on subsequent captures.